# How to escape single quotes in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column containing certain expressions stored as a text string which include single quotatons, such as 'missed transaction' (INCLUDING the quotations)

How can I use a where clause with such an occurance?

`select * from table where reason = ''missed transaction''`

doesn't work, and I can't use the replace function because it also requires single quotations in its syntax. Obscure problem, i know. But thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but most SQL systems use 'doubling' as escape sequences, e.g. to escape `'` use `''`. Did you try `'''missed transaction'''`?

Comment: If your query is coming from an application like .net, java, coldfusion, etc, use query parameters.  Escaping quotes is one of their benefits.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to escape the `'` by doubling them :

```
select * from table where reason = '''missed transaction''';
```

Comment: How to use Like in where cluase?

Answer (score 12):

The `q` quote syntax makes this sort of thing easier:

```
select * from table where reason = q'['missed transaction']'
```

Everything between the `'[` and the `]'` is interpreted literally, so no need to double all the quotes, however many there may be.

Comment: This is perfect for my surname search e.g. surnames like O'Reilly:  
SELECT * WHERE SURNAME LIKE q'[" + surname + "%]' ";