# How to add escape string from the output of oracle cursor?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have records from oracle in tuple, I'm trying to execute bulk insert statement in snowflake using python, but I'm facing escape character issue.

Input:

```
('Sample',1234,"Here is escape' need",9700,'final')
```

output:

```
('Sample',1234,'Here is escape'' need',9700,'final')
```

I have tried using regular expression to capture the string between double quotes and tried with replace function but it is not worked.

Input:

```
('Sample',1234,"Here is escape' need",9700,'final')
```

output:

```
('Sample',1234,'Here is escape'' need',9700,'final')
```

Comment: Hi @S3DEV I have tried the above format it not working in the target database, So I'm looking for the output as mentioned.

Comment: I have removed my previous comment.  Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906392/6340496) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can split values by coma and iterate over parts searching parts with double quotes and replace them:

```
inp = "('Sample',1234,\"Here is escape' need\",9700,'final')"
out = inp
for s in inp.strip("()").split(","):
    if s.startswith("\"") and s.endswith("\"") and "'" in s:
        out = out.replace(s, "'" + s[1: -1].replace("'", "\"") + "'")
```

Result:

```
('Sample',1234,'Here is escape" need',9700,'final')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to modify anything?  Tuples can be inserted directly via parameter binding:

```
t = ('Sample',1234,"Here is escape' need",9700,'final')
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)", [t])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion let me try it and get back you in case if I need further assistance.

Comment: Hans, Its works only when input has single record, What if I have multiple records with below format: t = ('Sample',1234,"Here is escape' need",9700,'final'),('Sample',1234,"Here is escape' need",9700,'final') I'm facing following error while using parameter binding **TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**. Could you please assist me on this

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this.